# Finalfit package - 'Error in variable_type(d_variable) : object 'out' not found'

Tags: r

I am trying to visualise a model using plotting from the excellent **finalfit** package (ie the final steps of 7.3.7 here https://argoshare.is.ed.ac.uk/healthyr_book/fitting-more-complex-models.html)

```r
dependent <- "vftot_w3"
explanatory <- c("age11IQ",  "ageyears_w3", "Sex.factor", "MCR.factor.w3", "bld_choles_w3")
explanatory_multi <- c("age11IQ", "ageyears_w3", "Sex.factor", "MCR.factor.w3")

MCRw3to5 %>% 
  ff_plot(dependent, explanatory_multi)

***Error message** - Error in variable_type(d_variable) : object 'out' not found*
```

I've a feeling it might be a problem with an underlying function but would be grateful for any suggestions.

Thank you

Donncha

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with the people who created finalfit and was advised that this is most likely a problem with the underlying functionality of ff_plot. On their recommendation, I used coefficient_plot instead, and it worked with no problem. It was explained that ff_plot is a wrapper for coefficient, OR and HR plots - it's a 'convenience function'. It's not used very often so likely that if there was a problem with its functionality it wouldn't get spotted very quickly.